# docker exe into container does not show container id?

Tags: docker

When I enter a nginx container, it does not show container id on the prompt.

Also the nginx is not behaving as expected, and I have triple checked the html file that it serves.  It is showing the "Welcome to Nginx" when that html file does not exist anywhere in the container.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-194 ~]$ docker -v
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5/1.9.1


[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-194 ~]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
813b76df0094        quikordernginx                  "nginx -g 'daemon off"   6 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        80/tcp, 443/tcp                                    mad_banach
bef84977861e        nscithelp/adminrenderclient:    "nginx -g 'daemon off"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes                                                           small_wozniak
bdaa17e05c9d        nscithelp/adminrenderservice:   "npm start"              6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:1338->1338/tcp                             big_banach
2c9381e15f28        nscithelp/renderservice:        "npm start"              6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:1337->1337/tcp, 8000/tcp                   modest_rosalind
7096fa7ec8de        nscithelp/phoenixservices:      "npm start"              6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes                                                           prickly_mcnulty
2e15c84fed6b        jenkinssaved                    "/bin/sh -c 'BUILD_ID"   4 days ago          Up 5 hours          0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp   sick_carson
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-194 ~]$ docker exec -it bef8 bash
root@ip-10-0-0-194:/#
```

Comment: I figured it out... That container bef8 is using --net=host flag

Comment: Post it as an answer, please! Then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... That container bef8 is using --net=host flag